# vsFTPd stopped working after update

Tags: 12.04, vsftpd

I have just updated to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) from Ubuntu Server 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot).

It updated my vsFTPd installation, and it seems that something has changed :/ I use PAM authentication. What could have changed to cause this?

When trying to connect to the FTP server I get this error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

I tried googling it, and it said to add `allow_writable_root=YES` to the configuration file - however when I try this and try restarting vsftpd it can't restart. Why?

Here is how I actually fixed it:

```
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_3.0.2-3_amd64.deb -O vsftpd.deb
dpkg -i vsftpd.deb
echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
service vsftpd reload
```

And voila :)

Comment: Link, you provided for `wget` parameter, is dead. Probably, because version `3.0.2-3` is now out. Anyone facing this problem, should visit [this site](http://packages.debian.org/hu/sid/amd64/vsftpd/download) to get correct link. Above mentioned link is for 64-bit platform. To find links for this package for other platforms, like for example 32-bit, follow to [this page](http://packages.debian.org/hu/sid/vsftpd) and scroll down to `Download vsftpd` section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have this issue as well and think it's because of the new vsFTPd update to enhance security, so in the meantime I use this solution.

1. I chmod the folder that my FTP user comes in to as he/she first login (root folder) by using this in the terminal: `sudo chmod a-w /home/user`

   You can change `/home/user` to whatever is your FTP user's root folder.
2. Create a subfolder within the folder, either by the use of GUI, or if you only have a terminal, it's: `sudo mkdir /home/user/newfolder`

Now you should be able to log in and read write within the "newfolder". You will NOT be able to write in the root folder itself from the FTP client with the chmod a-w, so that is the reason for the subfolder, and there you can.

I guess there will be a fix in a not-so-long time, but in the meantime I hope this helps.

Comment: The only fix I can find is to install vsftpd-ext and replace vsftpd which allows the use of allow_writable_root, but it only comes as a .tar.gz file, and I am very new to linux and can't seem to get it to build :/ in the end i just forced a downgrade to the old version of vsftpd I used to run

Comment: Worked for me. The owner of the homedir has to create the folder, not the root.

Comment: Isnt doing a chmod a-w "forbidden" by the linux jedi masters? since youd be granting 666 permission?

Answer (score 9):

Somebody backported the feature to add `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` from version 3.0.0 to 2.3.5 (see [this blog entry](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2012/10/making-vsftpd-with-chrooted-users-work-again/)).

To install on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), run the following commands as root:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:thefrontiergroup/vsftpd
apt-get update
apt-get install vsftpd
echo allow_writeable_chroot=YES >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

**Note** that [there seems to an option](http://www.benscobie.com/fixing-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/) `allow_writable_chroot=YES` in vsftpd-ext - note the mssing **e**! (or is this a typo in the blog post?)

Comment: +1 - this certainly seems like the best option, and thanks to The Frontier Group for providing this PPA. But users should note that this takes you "off-piste". Due to the nature of what it does, vsftpd is a little exposed security-wise, and should a vulnerability be found in vsftpd in the future, then users are dependent on the PPA owner to update it, or users will need to find another solution at that time. It would be wise to subscribe to the ubuntu-security-announce mailing list and watch for vsftpd security announcements if you go down this route.

Comment: Our DEVOPS team created that package - leave a comment on the blog article if you have any individual problems you need help solving and they'll assist you.

Answer (score 6):

vsFTPd 3.0.0 adds a configuration option,

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

to again enable the previous behavior (source: *[Fixing 500 OOPS: vsFTPd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()](http://www.benscobie.com/fixing-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/)*, comment from Brian K. White).

Unfortunately, 3.0.0 is not yet packaged by Ubuntu. So in the meantime, downgrade to some older version. For example, I am using this one on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin): http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric-updates/vsftpd

Comment: Could you add instructions how to install the Oneiric package you linked? Should I manually download the package? I suppose adding oneiric-updates to my repositories will mess up things quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing thing as user Kristian it does:
It worked for me. The username I use is 'john'. Replace it for the username you want.

`sudo chmod a-w /home/john` - Removes permission for all users to delete or modify a file.

`sudo mkdir /home/john/ftp` - Creates a folder named 'ftp' in the home dir of user 'john'

`sudo chown -Rv john.john /home/john/ftp` - Changes ownership of the dir to group 'john' and user 'john'.

Answer (score 0):

## Why?

*Taken and adapted from my own answer in [bug 1065714](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1065714).*

In order to keep stable releases stable, updates after release are only considered under specific circumstances. Details of the process and of the criteria required are listed here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#When

This does make it difficult for users of the LTS release to have writeable chroots, since the upstream vsftpd project decided to release without this feature at the time that 12.04 was released. Now that 12.04 is released and the fix doesn't meet the above criteria, I don't think this will change for 12.04. But note that the [Stable Release Updates Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sru) makes the final decision on this, and an update hasn't been proposed to them.

If you'd like a newer version of vsftpd to be made generally available for users who do want to use the "allow_writeable_chroot" option, then the backports repository is an appropriate venue for this. With a backport, users who want the feature could just add the backports repository and install vsftpd from there. You can find out more about backports and how to request one here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports

In the meantime, The Frontier Group has kindly provided a PPA, as described in lumbric's answer. Or you can use one of the other answers here that works for you.