# VSFTPD configuration problems with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vsftpd

So I upgraded my Ubuntu Server to 12.04 LTS today and now VSFTPD wont work. I think it is related to this [VSFTPd stopped working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128180/vsftpd-stopped-working-after-update#_=_)

However, unlike the asker in that post, I am not getting any error messages. When I log on, I get

```
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed
```

I know the password is correct,and I have tried multiple users. vsftpd.log shows nothing other than:

```
Tue May  1 15:19:48 2012 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.1.133"
Tue May  1 15:19:53 2012 [pid 1] [USERNAME] FAIL LOGIN: Client "192.168.1.133"
```

Syslog shows nothing. Here is my VSFTPD.conf (mostly default):

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
check_shell=NO
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

I tried the command mentioned in the previous question to no avail.

```
sudo chmod a-w /home/user
```

Thanks, I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In vsftpd.conf

Make the following change :
pam_service_name=**ftp**

Save your change and restart the ftp server.

Comment: Thanks very much! You wouldn't believe how much of a pain this has been!

Comment: Care to elaborate on your solution?

Comment: Where can I find vsftpd.conf..

Comment: This fixed my problem! WTF. Why is this not the default service name, uhh? What is a PAM service?

Comment: this ends up giving me:

    500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_result
    Login failed.
    421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.10 the name of the pam file is correct. See me comment below. Don't change it, please!

Answer (score 1):

There are several Reason why you may get this reason.

Firewall-->>Tcp_wrapper-->>PAM-->>SElinux-->>FTPService-->> File.

1. First Check if the given user is blocked or not in 
   /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
   /etc/vsftpd/user_list
2. Check SElinux Context or Boolean for the Same.
3. Check in PAM directory   file.
   /etc/pam.d/vsftpd

auth       required     pam_shells.so

if user is not having required shell like in 
/etc/shells 
then it will give same error
check getent passwd username 
match given shell with /etc/shells.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first login to the FTP through firefox or a browser, so you are sure to get a response why you are not able to log in.

This is just as a precausion to confirm if it is the login credentials itself or not.

Answer (score 0):

If running an amd64 kernel, you will need to add the following to your `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that current pam configuration for vsftp includes a requirement to have a valid shell something you want to avoid in case of an FTP user.

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

The only thing you have to do is to comment last line **auth    required    pam_shells.so**. So this is no required.

Or add a login to all your ftp users.

Changing the name as suggested in the other comment is no point as you loose the deny file.