# vsftpd: 530 Login incorrect

Tags: server, ftp

I can't get `vsfptd` working on Ubuntu 12.04.

my `vsftpd.conf` file looks like this, and I try to connect with a local user:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Error message in FileZilla:

```
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ****
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
```

Comment: try restarting the vsftpd. >sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart I had the same issue, but this worked for me.

Comment: Another thing to check :
what is the login shell for the user.
is that shell present in /etc/shells

Comment: Please how can I modify the /etc/shells ?

Comment: For me, there was just wrong format for the user in /etc/passwd - i needed to set the right home dir, shell, and the `,,,` part.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit **vsftpd.conf** (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

> pam_service_name=**ftp**

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> & enter to save then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

**Source:** [VSFTPD configuration problems with 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/137390/179042)

Comment: This problem also, can be solved in debian7 by this answer.

Comment: What is the rationale behind this one?

Comment: You are disabling default access control via PAM, because default "ftp" has no rules. 
The default `pam_service_name=vsftp` uses the file `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`.
This file by default requires FTP users to have a shell listed in `/etc/shells` and requires them **not** to be listed in `/etc/ftpusers`.

Comment: Solved me the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: @JeroenVermeulenBVBA +1 you are right. I fear some people just don't know what's actually happening underneath and why it appears to "work".

Comment: This solved my problem on Ubuntu 14.04 too ! I wish I understood why but thanks anyway !

Comment: Wow,Wroked!. It amazing error can you give me description?

Comment: Oh well thanks for this! It's no longer stated in the current Ubuntu Server Guide (17.4)...

Comment: Please look at the comment from @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost

Answer (score 20):

By default vsFTPd uses the file `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`. 
This file by default requires FTP users to have a shell listed in `/etc/shells` and requires them **not** to be listed in `/etc/ftpusers`.
If you check those 2 things your probably find what the problem is.

Comment: I think this should be the accept answer because it points out where is the problem.

Comment: How does one make sure the FTP user has one of these shells? Asking for a friend...

Comment: @Allen This is defined in the file `/etc/passwd`. Each line is the info about one user. The fields are separated by a colon (:). The 7th field contains the path to the shell binary of the user.

Comment: Apart from editing the `passwd` file directly, you can use `usermod -s /bin/bash YOUR_USERNAME`

Answer (score 9):

I did not need to change the `vsftpd.conf`. Only needed to make sure that a shell was set in my `/etc/passwd` file, that also was lited in `/etc/shells`.

So basically after `useradd` without a shell I needed to make sure the home directory was created and that the user had `/bin/bash` as it's shell.

Comment: Thanks that's what happened to me. The other solutions worked by removing all safety mechanisms, this one was actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I met this problem when I tried to login in with `root` and I just solved it.

```
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
```

**Solution:**

Check the following file (it contains list of users disallowed FTP access):

```
/etc/ftpusers
```

[image: ftpusers]

In my case, I commented out `root` from the file, then it worked.

Comment: I did same to be able to login as root, but didn't worked

Comment: Not a good idea to enable thoses users!  There is a security reason why they are refused.

Answer (score 3):

Please make some changes in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

If you want to set access by default `/var/www` directory for local user you can do that with below line:

```
local_root=/var/www
```

Now save and exit.

Restart `vsftpd` server using:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: This is the same as a [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/413694/207702), and as someone already commented there [it’s not a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413677/vsftpd-530-login-incorrect#comment968145_413694).

Answer (score 2):

The suggested resolution did not work for me. I gave up on the `ftp` user, and switched my attention to the `ubuntu` user. I made sure there was a password associated with the `ubuntu` user.

I made sure to enable passive mode, and set `local_enable=YES` in the `vsftpd.conf` file.

I was able to authenticate just fine using the `ubuntu` account. And I successfully uploaded a large file to my Amazon Ubuntu FTP server. Clearly there was something amiss with the `ftp` user.

Answer (score 0):

I used Ubuntu 18.04 and LetsEncrypt certificates for TLS encryption. What worked was changing the name of the `pam_service_name=ftp`
the error I was getting in Filezilla was:

```
"GnuTLS error -15": An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Reference: [FTPS set up in ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-18-04/#5-limiting-user-login)